# testing cloudinary direct image upload with capybara rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, cloudinary

I'm trying to test cloudinary direct uploading through capybara but capybara is saying that it cannot find the image upload field. How do you test direct uploading?

picture_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature "User Pictures" do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  describe "Uploading an image" do 
    describe "for profile photo" do 
      it "raises an error when clicked outside cropping image so image is not cropped" do
        visit new_user_picture_path(user)
        attach_file('#photo upload', "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/images/PRATIQUE_BIG.png")
        click_on "Valider Photo"
        expect(page).to have_content "SVP crop votre image et celle-ci doit mesurer au moins 100 x 100px"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

new picture page

```
= form_for(@photo, :url => url, role: "form") do |f|          
                .form_line.form-group
                    .upload_button_holder
                        = link_to "Parcourir", "#", class: "btn btn-default upload_button form-control"
                        #photo-upload= f.cl_image_upload :image, class: "form-control" 
                    %span.status
                .form-group
                    .form_control
                        .preview
                = f.hidden_field :crop_x 
                = f.hidden_field :crop_y 
                = f.hidden_field :crop_w 
                = f.hidden_field :crop_h 
                .form-group
                    = f.submit "Valider Photo", class: "btn btn-lg btn-success" 

            = hidden_field_tag :direct, params[:direct] 
        %p= link_to "Retour à Mon Profil", profile_path(current_user.user_code)
 // Configure Cloudinary jQuery plugin 
 = cloudinary_js_config
```

Capybara then gives back `Unable to find file field "photo-upload"`

Answer (score 0):

The name of the field in case of `cl_image_upload` is always `file`. `photo-update` is the id of the surrounding div. You can assign an id to the file input field by passing `html: {id: "my-id"}` to `cl_image_upload`. BTW. class also belongs inside the `html` hash parameter.